# How to extend css modules in next js?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, css-modules

I am new to nextjs and I have a question about CSS modules

I have a Product component that looks like this

```
import styles from "./Product.module.css"
function Product({className=""}) {
  return (
    <div class={`${styles.container} ${className}`}>
      <p className={styles.title}>product</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Then I want to create another component that is called ProductCard which uses the Product component but needs to extend the p tag inside it

```
import styles from "./ProductCard.module.css"
function ProductCard() {
  return (
    <div class={styles.container}>
        <Product className={styles.product}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

How can I extend the p tag style in my Product component with a className given ProductCard

Comment: I reproduced and your current code works, you are passing a `className` prop to your `Product` component, and then put it on the `div`. Do you want to pass a second prop  and put it on the `p` tag this time ? Or do you have something that does not work ?

Comment: As it is JSX, you need to change `class` by `className` by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an additional custom prop and pass it to the `p` element.  Using an object will allow you to pass any prop to the `p` element.  See React's docs on [props in JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#props-in-jsx), [MDN spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), and [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).

```
function Product({ className, titleProps, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <div className={`${styles.container} ${className ?? ''}`} {...rest}>
      <p {...titleProps}>product</p>
    </div>
  );
}

function ProductCard() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Product
        className={styles.product}
        titleProps={{ className: styles.title }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import styles from "./Product.module.css"
function Product({className=""}) {
  const classes = {
      'product': `${styles.product}`
  }
  return (
     <div class={`${styles.container} ${classes[className]}`}>
        <p className={styles.title}>product</p>
     </div>
  )
}

import styles from "./ProductCard.module.css"
function ProductCard() {
  return (
      <div class={styles.container}>
          <Product className='product' />
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.